# Reactjst-WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state

Tags: reactjs, django, websocket

I created chat system using Django and Reactjs,when i want to send Message then in console give me Error of : WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
my code is

let socket = new WebSocket(ServerUrl.WS_BASE_URL + `ws/users/${CommonUtil.getUserId()}/chat/`);

```
const messageSubmitHandler = (event) =\> {
event.preventDefault();
if (inputMessage) {
socket.send(
JSON.stringify({
action: SocketActions.MESSAGE,
message: inputMessage,
user: CommonUtil.getUserId(),
roomId: CommonUtil.getActiveChatId(match),
})
);
 }
setInputMessage('');
};




\<div className="flex-grow-0 py-3 px-4 border-top"\>
\<form onSubmit={messageSubmitHandler}\>
\<div className="input-group"\>
 \<input
 onChange={(event) =\> setInputMessage(event.target.value)}
 onKeyUp={chatMessageTypingHandler}
 value={inputMessage}
 id="chat-message-input"
type="text"
className="form-control"
placeholder="Type your message"
autoComplete="off"
/\>
\<button id="chat-message-submit" className="btn btn-outline-warning"\>
Send
\</button\>
\</div\>
\</form\>
\</div\>
```

I search in stackOverflow but there is no Such solution